# How to internationalize error message from Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, localization, internationalization, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase-Authentication for Android and all of the error messages returned from the server calls in english only.

When I use `ex.getLocalizedMessage()` from the exception it doesn't apply the user's language.

What I am planing to do for now is to check the instance of the exception and load my own message, however I am very resistant to do that.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this @jairobjunior?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I see is to check returned exception errorCode and do the mapping on your client side, like

```
switch(errorCode)
  case ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD
    return "Dear jairo, wrong pwd."
```

Answer (score -2):

`getLocalizedMessage()` comes from [Throwable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Throwable.html) class. According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Throwable.html#getLocalizedMessage()):

> Creates a localized description of this throwable. Subclasses may
>   override this method in order to produce a locale-specific message.
>   For subclasses that do not override this method, the default
>   implementation returns the same result as getMessage().

Now, If you want to do so, you have create subclass of `Throwable` and override its `getLocalizedMessage()` method.

And the last thing, in that method implementation just return String of default `Locale` using [Localization](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html).

Comment: Hey @Chintan Soni, I am not sure if you understood my question. Firebase has a callback with the instance of the exception which could be one of these: [Firebase exception](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthException). I understand what you said, but the implementation should be coming from Firebase API. So you answer for this question is not accurate.